# EntityFramework and XML

Tags: c#, xml, t-sql, entity-framework

We have a application that is making requests to a MSSQL DB via Entity Framework. One column in one table is a serialized C# class, stored in XML format. We would like to perform simple XPath queries against this data from C#. Currently we simply load the dataset, parse the XML via linq-to-XML then query the structure. This is of course the absolute worst way to solve this problem, so I'm looking for alternatives.

MS SQL 2008 can query XML data, so how do I do that through EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stored procedure.  Or you can run dynamic SQL using ObjectQuery.  Other than that, I don't know of any way to use the XML features of SQL Server through EF.

Comment: Yeah, that could work, however we end up having to combine it with several other linq clauses.